# I did not get a verification e-mail on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, email-verification

I want to make a proposal in Area 51 but I could not.

In my profile I have a hyperlink to verify my account, but it won't send anything.

I do not have to verify it on my other accounts just at Area 51. It is not in my spam folder. I have checked it.

Comment: I use to type `@gmial.com`, how about you?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your account, and the email address that you entered differs from the email address associated with your OpenId by one character. It's probably a typo.